# Unhandled Exception: type 'IconData' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add an Icon in the last column of the table so that it comes in the Pdf UI. The dependecy which I'm using is ***pdf: ^2.0.0, flutter_full_pdf_viewer: ^1.0.6, printing: ^4.0.0*** but I'm getttig an error stating as `Unhandled Exception: type 'IconData' is not a subtype of type 'String'`. Can i get to know what mistake I'm doing casue I'm thinking as I'm not declaring the Icon as a String, so can i get to know what's wrong here?

```
class Product {
  const Product(this.serial,
      this.articleNumber,
      this.addresseeName,
      this.remark,
      this.image
      );

  final String serial;
  final String articleNumber;
  final String addresseeName;
  final String remark;
  final IconData image;


  getIndex(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return serial;
      case 1:
        return articleNumber;
      case 2:
        return addresseeName;
      case 3:
        return remark.toString();
      case 4:
        return image;
    }
    return '';
  }

}
```

```
final products = <Product>[
    Product('1', 'RK1234567890IN', '', 'NOT DELIVERED', Icons.ac_unit),
    Product('2', 'RM0987654321IN', 'Ramesh', 'DELIVERED \n ( To : name)\n29-01-2021 10:03:43', Icons.ac_unit),
    Product('3', 'RL4345424741IN', 'Suresh', 'DELIVERED \n ( To : name)\n29-01-2021 10:30:13', Icons.ac_unit),
    Product('4', 'RO9638642753IN', '', 'NOT DELIVERED', Icons.ac_unit),
  ];
```

And this is how I'm declaring the table

```
  pw.Widget _contentArticleTable(pw.Context context) {
    const tableHeaders = [
      'SERIAL',
      'ARTICLE NUMBER',
      'ADDRESSEE NAME',
      'REMARK',
      'SIGNATURE'
    ];
    return pw.Table.fromTextArray(
      cellAlignment: pw.Alignment.centerLeft,
      headerDecoration: pw.BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: const pw.BorderRadius.all(pw.Radius.circular(2)),
        color: PdfColors.grey200,
      ),
      headerHeight: 25,
      cellHeight: 40,
      cellAlignments: {
        0: pw.Alignment.center,
        1: pw.Alignment.center,
        2: pw.Alignment.center,
        3: pw.Alignment.center,
        4: pw.Alignment.center,
      },
      headerStyle: pw.TextStyle(
        color: PdfColors.blueGrey,
        fontSize: 10,
        fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
      ),
      cellStyle: const pw.TextStyle(
        color: PdfColors.black,
        fontSize: 10,
      ),
      rowDecoration: pw.BoxDecoration(
        border: pw.Border(
          bottom: pw.BorderSide(
            color: PdfColors.amber,
            width: .5,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      headers: List<String>.generate(
        tableHeaders.length,
            (col) => tableHeaders[col],
      ),
      data: List<List<String>>.generate(
        products.length,
            (row) => List<String>.generate(
          tableHeaders.length,
              (col) => products[row].getIndex(col),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: What widget do you using for displaying images?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass the IconData as String. You're probably passsing it as

```
child: Icon(
    "widget.icon", //remove the quotes or any string interpolation
     size: 16.0,
  ),
```

This is the correct way to use the icon.

```
child: Icon(
    widget.icon,
     size: 16.0,
  ),
```

Comment: No that's not how I'm declaring

Comment: Can you provide the widget do you using for displaying images/icons?

Answer (score 0):

This might be the error

```
  getIndex(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return serial;
      case 1:
        return articleNumber;
      case 2:
        return addresseeName;
      case 3:
        return remark.toString();
      case 4:
        return image; //this is fine if the condition is true but below might cause and error
    }
    return ''; //this causes the error during dart compilation on the condition this return a string value
  }
```

Comment: No it's not at all coming into that return statement I'm getting an error in case 4 itself as stated above even if the change the empty string to null in the last return statement.

Comment: what im saying is your ```getIndex()``` method dont have a datatype its basically a string..  Expirement with ```IconData getIndex()``` and ```String getIndex()```...Your method thinks the return type is string.It means this error ```Unhandled Exception: type 'IconData' is not a subtype of type 'String'```

Comment: So your getIndex expect a return value on all ```Case``` to be string. Then on your case 4 it becomes Icondata thats when you have error

Comment: As you said I tried by giving as ```dynamic getIndex(int index)``` but the data which i entered in the case 4 is getting printed in string even though i initialized it as Icon data(getting printed as -> ```IconData(U+0E7cF)```